# Using adapter function to add dynamic custom marker images to legend in AMCharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, amcharts4

I am using AMCharts4 to create this chart in React.

[mockup of chart i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s53jq.png)

I want to completely customize the legend to display the flag images of the countries instead of the default color bullets. I think I can achieve this by using an adapter to return html. I am using the flag-icon-css to generate the flag images so I want to do something like this:

```
 flag.adapter.add('href', function(href: any, target: any) {
          return <span className={target.dataItem.dataContext.dummyData.flag}></span>;
        });
      });
```

I have been relying heavily on this example from the docs: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/VqQvxX
I can't figure out what to add as the first argument to the adapter function. They use 'href' but I really want to use something like 'html' which i don't think exists and it's currently giving me the error: 'Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'' when I try to return that  from the adapter function.

I am currently trying to dynamically assign some dummyData to the series when they are created that takes the country iso code and puts it into a class name that the flag-icon package accepts. Like this:

```
            newSeries.dummyData = {
          flag: `flag-icon flag-icon-${ownershipItem.isoCode.toLowerCase()}`
        };
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to return html/jsx from an adapter function with amcharts? and if not is there another way to achieve this custom legend? Any help is appreciated. I will post some more detailed code below.

```
useEffect(
function() {
  if (topOwnershipMounted && CompanyTopOwnership) {
    topOwnershipChart.current = (() => {
      am4core.useTheme(am4themes_kelly);
      const newChart = am4core.create('topOwnershipChart', am4charts.XYChart);
      newChart.data = CompanyTopOwnership;
      newChart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = 'yyyy';
      newChart.minHeight = 300;

      // Declare Axes
      let countryAxis = newChart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      countryAxis.title.text = 'Percentage';
      let yearAxis = newChart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
      yearAxis.title.text = 'Year';

      newChart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
      let marker = newChart.legend.markers.template;
      marker.disposeChildren();

      //create line series
      CompanyTopOwnership.companyTopOwnerShips.map((ownershipItem: any) => {
        let newSeries = newChart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        newSeries.name = ownershipItem.countryName;
        const newSeriesData = ownershipItem.ownerShipPercentageDates.map((percentItem: any) => {
          return percentItem;
        });

        //assign data for flags
        newSeries.dummyData = {
          flag: `flag-icon flag-icon-${ownershipItem.isoCode.toLowerCase()}`
        };

        // Add custom image instead
        let flag = marker.createChild(am4core.Image);

        // use adapter to try and return custom html instead of marker
        flag.adapter.add('path', function(path: any, target: any) {
          // return <FlagIcon className='legendFlag' code='us' />;
          return <span className={target.dataItem.dataContext.dummyData.flag}></span>;
        });

        newSeries.data = orderBy(
          newSeriesData,
          ({ year }) => {
            return moment(year).format('YYYY');
          },
          ['asc']
        );

        newSeries.dataFields.dateX = 'year';
        newSeries.dataFields.valueY = 'percentage';
        newSeries.strokeWidth = 3;
        newSeries.tensionX = 0.7;
        newSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
      });

      return newChart;
    })();
  }
},
// eslint-disable-next-line
[CompanyTopOwnership, getCompanyData, topOwnershipMounted]
```

);

Comment: You can't use jsx/component names in AmCharts adapters. `href` expects a string URL to your image and  `path` refers to an [SVG path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) string, which explains the error you're getting. Note that the adapters correspond to the actual properties associated with the object, so the return value type must match the underlying property. More information on adapters [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/). Custom markers are mentioned [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Individual_custom_markers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @xorspark. Do you know how I might go about using a local path for the image instead of jsx?

Comment: That would probably would involve some webpack configuration (or whatever you're using) so that images can be referenced from your bundled JS, but I'm not an expert with those tools.